Themes isn't working on Ubuntu 24.04
I installed the themes in ./themes, enabled them in "gnome-tweak", but they aren't working.

What themes from where? Are you sure they are ready to work with Ubuntu 24.04 a new version of Gnome.

from gnome-look i tried material-black and orchis

TBH I do not use themes at all myself, but since GNOME 40 the project does not allow themes any more. If you want extensive theming then change to a different desktop.
Some sites say that themes support has been moved into a separate extension now:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3019/user-themes-x/
